# How to enable has_custom_metrics to true for cAdvisor in Kubernetes 1.6

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet, cadvisor

Can anyone tell me how to set the flag has_custom_metrics to true for cAdvisor in Kubernetes 1.6? Kubelet shows --enable-custom-metrics=true but I don't see it for cAdvisor when it is accessed it via web browser. The volume /etc/custom-metrics was mounted correctly with the file definition.json.

[image]

Comment: We are also experiencing the same issue, screenshot (https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/876195/31179286-33a06258-a939-11e7-8de5-15400dd2d6f2.png).